# expected constructor, destructor, or type converstion before '*' token

Tags: c++, templates, syntax, compiler-errors, syntax-error

So I have a binTree.h header file that looks like:

```
template<class T> class binTree {
public:
    binTree();
    ~binTree();
    void insert(T val);
    T find(T val) const;
    T remove(T val);

private:
    struct node {
        T val;
        node* left;
        node* right;

        node(T v, node* l, node* r) :
                val(v), left(l), right(r) {
        }
    };

    void destruct(node* n);
    void insert(T val, node* n);
    T find(T val, node* n) const;
    T remove(T val, node* n, node* parent);

    node* root;
};
```

Now in the binTree.cpp file I implement the following method just to be used in the .cpp file as you can see it is not declared in the header file. I am having trouble correctly declaring this method.

```
node* maximum(node* n) { // line 79
   if (n->right == null) {
      return n;
   } else {
      return maximum(n->right);
   }
}
```

I get the error:

```
line 79: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type converstion before '*' token
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to split header and implementation files of template class? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724036/splitting-templated-c-classes-into-hpp-cpp-files-is-it-possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `node` is not a type, even if you write:

```
template <class T>
binTree<T>::node* maximum(binTree<T>::node* n){}
```

`binTree<T>::node` is a dependent name not a type. 
Moreover the error you mentioned basically occurs when you do some processing outside any function block or do some other silly mistake like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958044/expected-constructor-destructor-or-type-conversion-before-token)

---

secondly if your class is templated you can not write the implementation in another cpp file, unless it is a specialization like:

```
binTree<int>::binTree()
{
    //some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement maximum function as a template

```
template<class T>
T* maximum(T* n) {...}
```